# Prompt to approve use of computer location using Google Maps auto complete

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, geolocation

I'm creating a registration form and using google maps API v3 to auto complete the address fields.

I've used [this code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

I'd like to prevent the "[the site's url] wants to use your computer's location..." browser prompt from appearing since i have no need for it. (the user will input their address which will be auto completed)

**Is it possible to use location auto complete without trying to retrieve the computer's location?**

If so, should I make changes to the `geolocate()` function mentioned in the code and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `geolocate` function if you have no need for it, and remove the `onFocus="geolocate()"` from the input box.  Instead you really  need to amend the `fillInAddress` function.  Presumably you'd want to add an event listener for when the value in the first text box gets updated.  You'd then need to use the Places service to look up addresses based on the users's input as they type (or perhaps you could just do it after they've clicked a submit button).

More like the other example in fact, at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox